# Why freemarker not reading my Java object (POJO)?

Tags: freemarker, datamodel

I am using freemarker to process html elements, inside the template file, it can read one of my legacy java object by giving `${form.fontStyle}`, but it doesn't read my newly created java object"

```
public class SectionHeaderInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// the form object holds the setting of the form.
private Form form;

// the form section object
private FormSection section;

private String languageText;

public String name;

public SectionHeaderInfo(Form form, FormSection section, String languageText) {
    this.form = form;
    this.section = section;
    this.languageText = languageText;
}
    public void getName() {
         return "whatever";
    }
```

I added `getName` just for testing, but it complains

> Caused by: freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException: For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this evaluated to a  (wrapper: com.xxx.SectionHeaderInfo):

I compared the two java classes, tried implements `TemplateModel, Serializable`, nothing can get it work. 
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Show us your FTL template.

Comment: Does it really say "to a (wrapper: com.xxx.SectionHeaderInfo)"? There supposed to be an FTL type before the "(wrapper" part. Also, do you know what `ObjectWrapper` does the FreeMarker `Configuration` using?